# What effect increased skills for enchanting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing skyrim and have retired.

When I played I was sure I made enchanting legendary several time.

That's because I have this super fortify enchanting potions I created with restoration glitches.

Then my daughter told me those potions, while increasing tons of stats, actually do not increase enchanting skills at all.

I look up some sources and I read this

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills

> Since Enchanting skill gains are based only **on the number of items
> enchanted, or soul gems used to recharge depleted items**, leveling
> Enchanting is no different the second time to the first. **Even potions
> of Fortify Enchant don't affect the skill gains.** Stocking up on filled
> soul gems and items to enchant, is what you need.

So, it seems enchanting is not like smithing. You can't make an item worth 1 million septims and increase enchanting from 15 to 100 in no time.

Am I correct? Am I missing something?

Also does enchanting an item with petty soul gems increase enchanting as much as enchanting items with grand soul gems?

Or is it just the number of "enchants" and "items" you do.

I am still pretty sured I increased enchanting easily before. I just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't believe the UESP?

Answer (score 2):

To simply put it there is 1 factor that determines the skill increase and that is the soul gem used. The higher the quality of the soul in the soul gem the more it will increase your enchanting while used. The enchant itself or the value of the weapon does not matter.

Enchants on the other hand DO differentiate in the the value increase (enchanting a weapon with banishing would increase the value much more then a fire enchant would).

A quick leveling strategy for enchanting (that works in tandem with blacksmithing) is to buy a lot of filled soul gems from a court wizard and a lot of leather and iron from a blacksmith. use the leathers and iron to make daggers, enchant the dagger with the most powerful enchant you can get (Banish, so it would be profitable to buy 1 banishment weapon and disenchant it but other weapon enchants would also work but yield fewer profits).

Once you used up all your soul gems enchanting the daggers you sell them to the court wizard/blacksmiths and then  just save, quit and start again (resetting all vendors) so you can buy new materials to craft and enchant the daggers.

This will help you level blacksmithing, speech and enchanting in one go while also filling your pockets with gold :)

Comment: I am pretty sure smithing is different. I can go from 15 to 100 by smithing just one good. Not so sure about enchanting

Comment: @user4951 one good? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I upgrade one item, boing, my smithing skill is 100. One bang from a hammer. Need very high fortify smithing apparel. Like 10k %

Comment: Any source of your claim?

Comment: @user4951 i'm unclear on waht you are talking about.